# Phpmailer configure

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have installed phpmailer for cpanel using composer successfully.

The location of PHPMailer is at

```
root\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer
```

now I want to use PHPmailer in one of my files at

`root\public_html`

What changes do I have to make to the following lines ?

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

the code is not working with the above configuration.The rest of code is same as that given in the documentation (with correct values filled)

Answer (score 1):

If your current working directory is `root\public_html` (I'm assuming you're on Windows since you're using `\` in paths) and you want to load the composer autoloader from there when it's stored in `root\vendor\autoload.php`, you should load it from a relative path like this:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Note that the namespace aliases (the `use` lines) do not change.

While this should work, a better solution is to add your app's root folder (in this example `root\`, wherever that is as an absolute path) to your php.ini's `include_path` setting, and that way the original `vendor/autoload.php` will work.

Comment: $mail - > Host ='localhost';
$mail -> port =587;

this configuration is not working while it worked for me in the old version of phpmailer

Comment: That's a different question, but port 587 on localhost is very unlikely to work because it will not be presented with a valid TLS certificate matching the `localhost` name. Don't use encryption when talking to localhost. It may have worked in the past if you were using PHP versions older than 5.6.